# Deploying war file in Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-applications, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, war

I have a war file of my application which works fine when executed from the command line in local. I´m uploading it to Amazon´s Elastic Beanstalk using Tomcat but when I try to access the URL I receive a 404 error.

The problem is something related to my war file or I have to change Amazon´s configuration?

Many thanks.

Logs:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-access_log
-------------------------------------
88.26.90.37 (88.26.90.37) - - [23/Jul/2017:18:55:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 1004 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"



-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/error_log
-------------------------------------
[Sun Jul 23 18:54:15 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.32 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 23 18:55:23 2017] [error] server is within MinSpareThreads of MaxClients, consider raising the MaxClients setting



-------------------------------------
/var/log/tomcat8/host-manager.2017-07-23.log
-------------------------------------




-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/access_log
-------------------------------------
88.26.90.37 - - [23/Jul/2017:18:55:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 1004 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"



-------------------------------------
/var/log/tomcat8/tomcat8-initd.log
-------------------------------------




-------------------------------------
/var/log/tomcat8/localhost_access_log.txt
-------------------------------------
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jul/2017:18:55:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 1004



-------------------------------------
/var/log/tomcat8/manager.2017-07-23.log
-------------------------------------




-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-activity.log
-------------------------------------
  + EB_APP_DEPLOY_BASE_DIR=/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps
  + rm -rf /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
  + rm -rf '/usr/share/tomcat8/conf/Catalina/localhost/*'
  + rm -rf '/usr/share/tomcat8/work/Catalina/*'
  + mkdir -p /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
[2017-07-23T18:54:13.069Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/02start_xray.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-07-23T18:54:13.290Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/02start_xray.sh] : Completed activity.
[2017-07-23T18:54:13.291Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/03_stop_proxy.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-07-23T18:54:13.629Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/03_stop_proxy.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Executing: service nginx stop

  Executing: service httpd stop
  Stopping httpd: [FAILED]
[2017-07-23T18:54:13.629Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/03deploy.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-07-23T18:54:14.089Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/03deploy.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir
  + EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=/tmp/deployment/application/ROOT
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_deploy_dir
  + EB_APP_DEPLOY_DIR=/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
  ++ wc -l
  ++ find /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT -maxdepth 1 -type f
  + FILE_COUNT=0
  ++ grep -Pi '\.war$'
  ++ find /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT -maxdepth 1 -type f
  ++ echo ''
  + WAR_FILES=
  + WAR_FILE_COUNT=0
  + [[ 0 > 0 ]]
  ++ readlink -f /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/../
  + EB_APP_DEPLOY_BASE=/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps
  + rm -rf /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
  + [[ 0 == 0 ]]
  + [[ 0 > 1 ]]
  + cp -R /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
  + chown -R tomcat:tomcat /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps
[2017-07-23T18:54:14.089Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/04config_deploy.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-07-23T18:54:14.652Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/04config_deploy.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k config_staging_dir
  + EB_CONFIG_STAGING_DIR=/tmp/deployment/config
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k config_deploy_dir
  + EB_CONFIG_DEPLOY_DIR=/etc/sysconfig
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k config_filename
  + EB_CONFIG_FILENAME=tomcat8
  + cp /tmp/deployment/config/tomcat8 /etc/sysconfig/tomcat8
[2017-07-23T18:54:14.653Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/05start.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-07-23T18:54:15.081Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/05start.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k tomcat_version
  + TOMCAT_VERSION=8
  + TOMCAT_NAME=tomcat8
  + /etc/init.d/tomcat8 status
  tomcat8 is stopped
  [  OK  ]
+ /etc/init.d/tomcat8 start
  Starting tomcat8: [  OK  ]
+ /usr/bin/monit monitor tomcat
  monit: generated unique Monit id ae33689ef3cf376bf23fa3b09041524e and stored to '/root/.monit.id'
[2017-07-23T18:54:15.082Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/09_start_proxy.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-07-23T18:54:19.022Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/09_start_proxy.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Executing: service httpd stop
  Stopping httpd: [FAILED]
  Executing: service httpd start
  Starting httpd: [  OK  ]
  Executing: /bin/chmod 755 /var/run/httpd

  Executing: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/healthd-track-pidfile --proxy httpd

  Executing: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/healthd-configure --appstat-log-path /var/log/httpd/healthd/application.log --appstat-unit usec --appstat-timestamp-on 'arrival'

  Executing: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/healthd-restart

[2017-07-23T18:54:19.022Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact.
[2017-07-23T18:54:19.022Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployPostHook] : Starting activity...
[2017-07-23T18:54:19.023Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployPostHook/03monitor_pids.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-07-23T18:54:20.047Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployPostHook/03monitor_pids.sh] : Completed activity.
[2017-07-23T18:54:20.047Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployPostHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post.
[2017-07-23T18:54:20.047Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1/StartupStage1/PostInitHook] : Starting activity...
[2017-07-23T18:54:20.048Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1/StartupStage1/PostInitHook/01processmgrstart.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-07-23T18:54:20.097Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1/StartupStage1/PostInitHook/01processmgrstart.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  + /usr/bin/monit
[2017-07-23T18:54:20.097Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1/StartupStage1/PostInitHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/postinit.
[2017-07-23T18:54:20.097Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1/StartupStage1] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application deployment - Command CMD-Startup stage 1 completed
[2017-07-23T18:54:20.098Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1/AddonsAfter] : Starting activity...
[2017-07-23T18:54:20.098Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation] : Starting activity...
[2017-07-23T18:54:20.098Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation/10-config.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-07-23T18:54:20.509Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation/10-config.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Disabled forced hourly log rotation.
[2017-07-23T18:54:20.510Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/addons/logpublish/hooks/config.
[2017-07-23T18:54:20.510Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1/AddonsAfter] : Completed activity.
[2017-07-23T18:54:20.510Z] INFO  [2048]  - [Application deployment OnFocus2307@1] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application deployment - Command CMD-Startup succeeded
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.363Z] INFO  [2808]  - [CMD-TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.363Z] INFO  [2808]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.364Z] INFO  [2808]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.364Z] INFO  [2808]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.364Z] INFO  [2808]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...



-------------------------------------
/var/log/tomcat8/catalina.2017-07-23.log
-------------------------------------
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.868 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.44
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.886 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jul 5 2017 19:02:51 UTC
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.886 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.44.0
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.887 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.887 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.9.32-15.41.amzn1.x86_64
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.887 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.887 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-2.b11.30.amzn1.x86_64/jre
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.887 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_131-b11
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.888 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.888 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/share/tomcat8
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.888 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/share/tomcat8
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.888 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -DJDBC_CONNECTION_STRING=
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.890 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms256m
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.891 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx256m
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.891 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:MaxPermSize=64m
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.891 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/tomcat8
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.891 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat8
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.891 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.awt.headless=true
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.892 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.892 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/cache/tomcat8/temp
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.897 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/tomcat8/conf/logging.properties
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.897 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.897 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
23-Jul-2017 18:54:18.284 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
23-Jul-2017 18:54:18.352 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
23-Jul-2017 18:54:18.371 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
23-Jul-2017 18:54:18.374 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
23-Jul-2017 18:54:18.377 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 2288 ms
23-Jul-2017 18:54:18.477 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
23-Jul-2017 18:54:18.479 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.44
23-Jul-2017 18:54:18.512 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
23-Jul-2017 18:54:27.482 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
23-Jul-2017 18:54:27.680 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT has finished in 9,162 ms
23-Jul-2017 18:54:27.691 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
23-Jul-2017 18:54:27.724 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
23-Jul-2017 18:54:27.747 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 9369 ms



-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log
-------------------------------------
[2017-07-23T18:52:59.225Z] INFO  [1780]  : Found enabled addons: ["logpublish", "logstreaming"].
[2017-07-23T18:52:59.227Z] INFO  [1780]  : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
[2017-07-23T18:52:59.227Z] INFO  [1780]  : Updating Command definition of addon logstreaming.
[2017-07-23T18:52:59.227Z] DEBUG [1780]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::CloudFormation::Init||Infra-WriteApplication2||files..
[2017-07-23T18:52:59.232Z] DEBUG [1780]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||ManifestFileS3Key..
[2017-07-23T18:52:59.515Z] INFO  [1780]  : Finding latest manifest from bucket 'elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-253743328849' with prefix 'resources/environments/e-mrdyfipmbp/_runtime/versions/manifest_'.
[2017-07-23T18:52:59.801Z] INFO  [1780]  : Found manifest with key 'resources/environments/e-mrdyfipmbp/_runtime/versions/manifest_1500835914428'.
[2017-07-23T18:52:59.818Z] INFO  [1780]  : Updated manifest cache: deployment ID 1 and serial 1.
[2017-07-23T18:52:59.818Z] DEBUG [1780]  : Loaded definition of Command CMD-PreInit.
[2017-07-23T18:52:59.818Z] INFO  [1780]  : Executing Initialization
[2017-07-23T18:52:59.819Z] INFO  [1780]  : Executing command: CMD-PreInit...
[2017-07-23T18:52:59.819Z] INFO  [1780]  : Executing command CMD-PreInit activities...
[2017-07-23T18:52:59.819Z] DEBUG [1780]  : Setting environment variables..
[2017-07-23T18:52:59.819Z] INFO  [1780]  : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-PreInit...
[2017-07-23T18:53:04.333Z] DEBUG [1780]  : Running stages of Command CMD-PreInit from stage 0 to stage 0...
[2017-07-23T18:53:04.333Z] INFO  [1780]  : Running stage 0 of command CMD-PreInit...
[2017-07-23T18:53:04.333Z] DEBUG [1780]  : Loaded 3 actions for stage 0.
[2017-07-23T18:53:04.333Z] INFO  [1780]  : Running 1 of 3 actions: InfraWriteConfig...
[2017-07-23T18:53:04.345Z] INFO  [1780]  : Running 2 of 3 actions: DownloadSourceBundle...
[2017-07-23T18:53:05.730Z] INFO  [1780]  : Running 3 of 3 actions: PreInitHook...
[2017-07-23T18:53:07.650Z] INFO  [1780]  : Running AddonsAfter for command CMD-PreInit...
[2017-07-23T18:53:07.650Z] INFO  [1780]  : Command CMD-PreInit succeeded!
[2017-07-23T18:53:07.651Z] INFO  [1780]  : Command processor returning results: 
{"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"","returncode":0,"events":[]}]}
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.518Z] DEBUG [2048]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.518Z] DEBUG [2048]  : Checking if the command processor should execute...
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.520Z] DEBUG [2048]  : Checking whether the command is applicable to instance (i-04e322b065f1ab8d7)..
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.520Z] INFO  [2048]  : Command is applicable to this instance (i-04e322b065f1ab8d7)..
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.520Z] DEBUG [2048]  : Checking if the received command stage is valid..
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.520Z] INFO  [2048]  : No stage_num in command. Valid stage..
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.520Z] INFO  [2048]  : Received command CMD-Startup: {"execution_data":"{\"leader_election\":\"true\"}","instance_ids":["i-04e322b065f1ab8d7"],"command_name":"CMD-Startup","api_version":"1.0","resource_name":"AWSEBAutoScalingGroup","request_id":"fb2b25c7-6fd7-11e7-87da-0d1616730116"}
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.520Z] INFO  [2048]  : Command processor should execute command.
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.520Z] DEBUG [2048]  : Storing current stage..
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.520Z] DEBUG [2048]  : Stage_num does not exist. Not saving null stage. Returning..
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.520Z] DEBUG [2048]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.520Z] DEBUG [2048]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.521Z] DEBUG [2048]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.522Z] INFO  [2048]  : Found enabled addons: ["logpublish", "logstreaming"].
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.524Z] INFO  [2048]  : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.525Z] INFO  [2048]  : Updating Command definition of addon logstreaming.
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.525Z] DEBUG [2048]  : Refreshing metadata...
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.954Z] DEBUG [2048]  : Refreshed environment metadata.
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.954Z] DEBUG [2048]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.956Z] DEBUG [2048]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.957Z] INFO  [2048]  : Found enabled addons: ["logpublish", "logstreaming"].
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.961Z] INFO  [2048]  : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.961Z] INFO  [2048]  : Updating Command definition of addon logstreaming.
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.962Z] DEBUG [2048]  : Loaded definition of Command CMD-Startup.
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.963Z] INFO  [2048]  : Executing Application deployment
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.964Z] INFO  [2048]  : Executing command: CMD-Startup...
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.964Z] INFO  [2048]  : Executing command CMD-Startup activities...
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.964Z] DEBUG [2048]  : Setting environment variables..
[2017-07-23T18:54:05.964Z] INFO  [2048]  : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-Startup...
[2017-07-23T18:54:06.242Z] DEBUG [2048]  : Running stages of Command CMD-Startup from stage 0 to stage 1...
[2017-07-23T18:54:06.242Z] INFO  [2048]  : Running stage 0 of command CMD-Startup...
[2017-07-23T18:54:06.242Z] INFO  [2048]  : Running leader election...
[2017-07-23T18:54:06.665Z] INFO  [2048]  : Instance is Leader.
[2017-07-23T18:54:06.666Z] DEBUG [2048]  : Loaded 7 actions for stage 0.
[2017-07-23T18:54:06.666Z] INFO  [2048]  : Running 1 of 7 actions: HealthdLogRotation...
[2017-07-23T18:54:06.678Z] INFO  [2048]  : Running 2 of 7 actions: HealthdHTTPDLogging...
[2017-07-23T18:54:06.680Z] INFO  [2048]  : Running 3 of 7 actions: HealthdNginxLogging...
[2017-07-23T18:54:06.681Z] INFO  [2048]  : Running 4 of 7 actions: EbExtensionPreBuild...
[2017-07-23T18:54:07.163Z] INFO  [2048]  : Running 5 of 7 actions: AppDeployPreHook...
[2017-07-23T18:54:09.688Z] INFO  [2048]  : Running 6 of 7 actions: EbExtensionPostBuild...
[2017-07-23T18:54:10.176Z] INFO  [2048]  : Running 7 of 7 actions: InfraCleanEbExtension...
[2017-07-23T18:54:10.181Z] INFO  [2048]  : Running stage 1 of command CMD-Startup...
[2017-07-23T18:54:10.181Z] DEBUG [2048]  : Loaded 3 actions for stage 1.
[2017-07-23T18:54:10.181Z] INFO  [2048]  : Running 1 of 3 actions: AppDeployEnactHook...
[2017-07-23T18:54:19.022Z] INFO  [2048]  : Running 2 of 3 actions: AppDeployPostHook...
[2017-07-23T18:54:20.047Z] INFO  [2048]  : Running 3 of 3 actions: PostInitHook...
[2017-07-23T18:54:20.097Z] INFO  [2048]  : Running AddonsAfter for command CMD-Startup...
[2017-07-23T18:54:20.510Z] INFO  [2048]  : Command CMD-Startup succeeded!
[2017-07-23T18:54:20.511Z] INFO  [2048]  : Command processor returning results: 
{"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"","returncode":0,"events":[]}]}
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.353Z] DEBUG [2808]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.354Z] DEBUG [2808]  : Checking if the command processor should execute...
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.356Z] DEBUG [2808]  : Checking whether the command is applicable to instance (i-04e322b065f1ab8d7)..
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.356Z] INFO  [2808]  : Command is applicable to this instance (i-04e322b065f1ab8d7)..
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.356Z] DEBUG [2808]  : Checking if the received command stage is valid..
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.356Z] INFO  [2808]  : No stage_num in command. Valid stage..
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.356Z] INFO  [2808]  : Received command CMD-TailLogs: {"execution_data":"{\"aws_access_key_id\":\"ASIAJSUYLCIZFOIKPO2A\",\"signature\":\"RPf86lrs\\\/c0114+EODhe8jxRJhs=\",\"security_token\":\"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\",\"policy\":\"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\"}","instance_ids":["i-04e322b065f1ab8d7"],"data":"822325d4-6fd8-11e7-8e3e-c7d19f2d4234","command_name":"CMD-TailLogs","api_version":"1.0","resource_name":"AWSEBAutoScalingGroup","request_id":"822325d4-6fd8-11e7-8e3e-c7d19f2d4234"}
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.356Z] INFO  [2808]  : Command processor should execute command.
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.356Z] DEBUG [2808]  : Storing current stage..
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.356Z] DEBUG [2808]  : Stage_num does not exist. Not saving null stage. Returning..
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.356Z] DEBUG [2808]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.356Z] DEBUG [2808]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.358Z] DEBUG [2808]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.359Z] INFO  [2808]  : Found enabled addons: ["logpublish", "logstreaming"].
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.362Z] INFO  [2808]  : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.362Z] INFO  [2808]  : Updating Command definition of addon logstreaming.
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.362Z] DEBUG [2808]  : Loaded definition of Command CMD-TailLogs.
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.362Z] INFO  [2808]  : Executing CMD-TailLogs
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.363Z] INFO  [2808]  : Executing command: CMD-TailLogs...
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.363Z] INFO  [2808]  : Executing command CMD-TailLogs activities...
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.363Z] DEBUG [2808]  : Setting environment variables..
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.363Z] INFO  [2808]  : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-TailLogs...
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.364Z] DEBUG [2808]  : Running stages of Command CMD-TailLogs from stage 0 to stage 0...
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.364Z] INFO  [2808]  : Running stage 0 of command CMD-TailLogs...
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.364Z] DEBUG [2808]  : Loaded 1 actions for stage 0.
[2017-07-23T18:55:36.364Z] INFO  [2808]  : Running 1 of 1 actions: TailLogs...



-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log
-------------------------------------




-------------------------------------
/var/log/tomcat8/localhost.2017-07-23.log
-------------------------------------
23-Jul-2017 18:54:27.562 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration$JerseyWebApplicationInitializer@161183dc]



-------------------------------------
/var/log/tomcat8/catalina.out
-------------------------------------
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=64m; support was removed in 8.0
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.868 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.44
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.886 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jul 5 2017 19:02:51 UTC
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.886 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.44.0
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.887 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.887 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.9.32-15.41.amzn1.x86_64
23-Jul-2017 18:54:17.887 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
```

Comment: What does "executed from the command line in local" mean?  Have you tried to deploy the war file to a local Tomcat instance?

Comment: I mean that I have used java-jar mywar.war and it has worked fine @stdunbar

Comment: That implies you're using something like Spring Boot or Wildfly Swarm then.  Regardless of the name, Tomcat on AWS will not be able to handle a runable Java program.  Try to use either the Java Elastic Beanstalk type or create a real war file.  If it won't run on a local Tomcat it won't run on the Tomcat Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: @stdunbar thanks for the information. I am indeed using Spring Boot. I´m going to try it with the Java Elastic Beanstalk. What do you mean with "create a real war file"? I thought my war file was normal.

Comment: If you can run the war file from the command line it's not "normal".  You would normally be **required** to have an application server like Tomcat/Wildfly/etc to use a war file.

Answer (score 0):

Check your logs for the reason: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html

Perhaps you are missing a JDBC driver? ;D

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have added the logs, could you please help me?

Comment: At a glance nothing shows up, i´d tail the tomcat log until the error arises or automate it using cloudwatch logs...